Frame invariance of the conservation of linear momentum at a solid-fluid boundary
The Conservation of Linear Momentum (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_momentum_equation) states that
$\rho \frac{D \mathbf{u}}{D t} = \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{\sigma} + \rho \mathbf{f}$ (1)
In the absence of body forces $\mathbf{f}$ and at steady state, $\boldsymbol{0} = \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{\sigma}$.
Imagine a small section of a boundary between an elastic solid and an inviscid fluid. Let's say that the pressure of the fluid is equal to 2 MPa. The equilibrium condition for such a scenario is that the normal stress is equal on both sides of the boundary, so let's set the principal stresses in the solid equal to 2 MPa perpendicular to the boundary, and 1 MPa parallel to it:

If the boundary is aligned with the coordinate axes, the system trivially satisfies the Conservation equation (Equation 1). But if I rotate the entire system by 30 degrees, there are discontinuities across the boundary.
My problem is, how do I express the equilibrium experienced by this system? I know that the boundary conditions at the edges of the system are not homogeneous, so do I need to consider (elastic) body forces in the $\mathbf{f}$ term?
